# Can an IFR civilian aircraft use a TACAN for DME distances?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach, dme, tacan

Flying the KRDR LOC RWY 35 approach. How do I get my DME distance to HONNE or CANLI? can we pick up DME distance from a TACAN? Just used GPS Overlay but can we get distance from the TACAN?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29846

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does help somewhat. The issue I had was that I couldn't pick up any distance at all when I was flying it. Even though I tuned the TACAN frequency in.

Comment: If you locate the vhf frequency that is paired with the tacan channel and have a separate frequency selector for the dme equipment (not common anymore) you can get dme from the tacan. My recollection is that the AIM used to show the paired vhf frequency/tacan channel.

Comment: @757toga: Or in ICAO [Annex 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1509.png).